# How to change the font of CalendarDatePicker popup in UWP

Tags: xaml, uwp

Hi I want to change the fontfamily and fontsize of CalendarDatePicker popup, the control has both property but it will only apply for the display text after date is selected not on the popup that opens when you want to select date.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change the `CalendarViewStyle` of your `CalendarDatePicker`. To change the `FontFamily` and `FontSize` you need to update the `DayItemFontFamily` and `DayItemFontSize` properties like following:

```
<CalendarDatePicker>
    <CalendarDatePicker.CalendarViewStyle>
        <Style TargetType="CalendarView">
            <Setter Property="DayItemFontFamily" Value="Comic Sans MS" />
            <Setter Property="DayItemFontSize" Value="8" />
        </Style>
    </CalendarDatePicker.CalendarViewStyle>
</CalendarDatePicker>
```

Also you can change a bunch of other useful properties like the `SelectedBorderBrush`, `TodayForeground`, `CalendarItemBackground`, `MonthYearItemFontFamily` and more.

The default style of the `CalendarView` can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299113.aspx) and more info about the `CalendarView` class can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.calendarview.aspx). I would suggest you read through the **Remarks** section, especially **Customizing the CalendarView's appearance**, where all properties are listed which change the appearance of the calendar.

I have used the font `Comic Sans MS` but for a full list of available fonts check [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700394.aspx).

Comment: Thank you Kristian, it is helpful and now I am able to set this property but when I am binding the same property I am getting one unhandled win32 exception.

Comment: You cant use regular `Binding` or `x:Bind` within a `Style`. One solution is to create a custom control which extends `CalendarDatePicker` and has the same `Style` and then create dependency properties for font family and fontsize, which uses `TemplateBinding`. I would suggest you post a new question.

Comment: @KristianVukusic could see if you have any input on my question here? Thanks!! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49113978/how-to-increase-the-font-size-of-the-date-that-is-selected-on-a-calendardatepick