# How to increase the font size of the date that is selected on a CalendarDatePicker

Tags: xaml, datepicker, uwp, windows-10-universal

I have a `CalendarDatePicker` control on my UWP app. I am not able to increase the size of the font of the date that is selected using the `FontSize` attribute.

**How can I easily do this without overriding a lot of styles?**

Here is the basic code I have:

```
<Page
    x:Class="CalendarPickerExample.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:CalendarPickerExample"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <CalendarDatePicker FontSize="30" />
    </Grid>

</Page>
```

No matter what size I set the `FontSize` attribute on the `CalendarDatePicker`, the size of the font of the selected date does not increase.

[image: FontSize on CalendarDatePicker]

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the properties of the control using Live Visual Tree tool, in your case you want to change the size of the internal TextBlock:

[image: Live Visual Tree]
[image: Live Property Explorer]

You can modify the TextBlock font size in a copy of the default style https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299110.aspx

As you can see, it is hardcoded to 15 in the default template:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="DateText"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                   Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumBrush}"
                   Text="{TemplateBinding PlaceholderText}"
                   Grid.Row="1"
                   FontSize="15"
                   Padding="12, 0, 0, 2"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center" />
```

Comment: Thanks! But how can i override just this property easily on the code?

Comment: I think the cleanest way to do that is to override the style of the control. So you copy the default XAML from the link above and paste it into your page resources, for example:

`<Page.Resources>

        <Style x:Key="CustomCalendarDatePickerStyle" TargetType="CalendarDatePicker">`

The you modify the font size on the TextBlock in your new style, and reference the style in the control:

`<CalendarDatePicker Style="{StaticResource CustomCalendarDatePickerStyle}" />`

Comment: Thanks! this worked. I went with this answer because it has zero code behind even though there is a lot of xaml to add :)

Comment: Could you also take a look at this other issue i am having? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49161273/how-to-easily-allow-users-to-update-styles-used-be-elements-in-xaml-uwp

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Visual Tree Extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwpcommunitytoolkit/extensions/visualtree) from the UWP Community Toolkit to grab the textbox control by name or type and modify its `FontSize` property:

```
 <CalendarDatePicker x:Name="Calender"/>
```

-

```
 Calender.FindDescendantByName("DateText").FontSize = 30;
```

Comment: thank you again for another answer! i went with @handsomegreg's answer since that had no code behind at all. thank you all the same!